# filter by taxonomy term = taxonomy term of referencing nodes

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, input-formats

I have a node type 'hotels'. These nodes have a reference to a vocabulary 'regions' and a field 'hotel_images'.

And I have a node type 'region_page' with also the reference to the vocabulary 'regions'. In these nodes I integrate a view with images of the field 'hotel_images'.

This view should be filtered by the 'regions'.

In case the node (type: region_page) is set to term 'xy' of the vocabulary 'regions' - only images of hotels for which the term 'xy' is also set should be displayed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific requirement to use taxonomy terms to create the relationship between 'hotels' nodes and 'region_page' nodes, I recommend to use the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module instead.

In your use case, you likely want to attach an [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field to the 'hotels' content type, that allows the content editor to point to a node of the content type 'region_page'.

If I understand it correctly, you already have a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) attached to your 'region_page' content types' display. Assuming you're using the [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module, you should add `Content: Nid` as your contextual filter in the particular View, create a relationship using `Entity Reference: Referencing entity` and then use this relationship for outputting the field 'hotel_images'.

In this way, when viewing a 'region_page' node, the View will show all images that are stored on 'hotels' nodes that have a reference to the particular 'region_page' node.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

But yes, there's a requirement to use taxonomy terms for the relationship. This is the only common thing. Both entity types (hotels and region_page) have this taxonomy reference.

I think you didn't understand it correctly.

Hotels have images. And a taxonomy reference (regions). 

There's 1 region_page per taxonomy term (a region). The region_page has also the reference to the taxonomy 'regions'. The region_page should display the images of all the hotels in the region.

Comment: Personally, if there is only one 'region_page' node for each taxonomy term, I would still use the Entity reference module in order to create a relation from 'hotels' nodes to 'region_page' nodes. Please, if I do not understand your question correctly, do let me know! However, I've created a local test setup and used taxonomy terms to create the desired situation, in my second answer I've summed up the steps to create the View that displays all 'hotel_images' that are on 'hotels' nodes having the same taxonomy term as the 'region_page' node currently being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) to attach a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to your 'region_page' content types' display, that you're required to use taxonomy terms to create a relationship between your 'hotels' and 'region_page' content, and that your vocabulary is named 'Regions'.

In the View, use `Content: Nid` as your contextual filter and add the `Content: Taxonomy terms on node` as a relationship. Then, add `Taxonomy term: Content using Regions` as an additional relationship and mark it required. In the remainder of this answer, I assume that the identifier of this second relationship is 'field_regions'.

The 'field_regions' relationship can be selected for outputting the field 'hotel_images'. You probably want to add a filter criteria using `(field_regions) Content: Type (= Hotels)`, to prevent the output of row(s) from the content type 'region_page' that have the same taxonomy term selected (i.e., the 'region_page' node that is currently being displayed).